# ¿Como evitar ir al siguiente registro despues de editar DataGridViewTextBoxColumn y presionar la tecla Enter?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, datagridview

Cuando se esta esta editando una celda y se finaliza la edición presionando Enter se pasa al siguiente registro y preciso que se quede en el mismo registro que se esta editando.

Capturando el evento KeyDown del DataGridView y cancelando el Enter se consigue el efecto de que no pase al siguiente registro si no se esta editando, pero cuando se esta editando la celda lo sigue haciendo.

Answer (score 1):

Se pudo resolver con el siguiente código:

```
private void dgvOrigen_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  SendKeys.Send("{UP}");
}
```